# Customizing field in wordpress form

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been sorting out a phone-field that have not been working for a while.

It uses the profile-field from woocommerce, and hooks from a external plugin as its connected to "wishlists".

The code:

```
    function my_nmgr_add_phone_field( $fields, $args ) {
if ( isset( $fields['nmgr_phone'] ) ) {
    $wishlist_id = $args['wishlist']->get_id();
    $selected_value = get_post_meta( $wishlist_id, 'nmgr_phone', true );
    if ( empty( $selected_value ) ) {
        $selected_value = '';
    }

    // Save the selected value if the form has been submitted
    if ( isset( $_POST['nmgr_phone'] ) ) {
        $selected_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['nmgr_phone'] );
        $result = update_post_meta( $wishlist_id, 'nmgr_phone', $selected_value );
        if ( $result ) {
            echo '<script>console.log("nmgr_phone value updated: ' . $selected_value . '");</script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script>console.log("Failed to update nmgr_phone value");</script>';
        }
    }

    echo '<script>console.log("Selected value: ' . $selected_value . '");</script>';

    $fields['nmgr_phone'] = array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'label'       => __( 'Telefon', 'my-text-domain' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'Telefon', 'my-text-domain' ),
        'required'    => true,
        //'fieldset'    => 'profile',
        'value'       => $selected_value,
        'priority'    => 60,
    );
    
}

return $fields;} add_filter( 'nmgr_requested_fields', 'my_nmgr_add_phone_field', 10, 2 );
```

The field does save and display the value in backend, however if saving in frontend it loops until I reload the page.

I then reworked the code:

```
function my_nmgr_modify_existing_field( $fields ) {
if ( isset( $fields['nmgr_phone'] ) ) {
    $wishlist_id = get_the_ID(); 
    $selected_value = get_post_meta( $wishlist_id, 'nmgr_phone', true ); 
    
    $fields['nmgr_phone']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['nmgr_phone']['label'] = 'Telefon';
    $fields['nmgr_phone']['priority'] = '60';
    $fields['nmgr_phone']['value'] = $selected_value;

} } return $fields; add_filter( 'nmgr_requested_fields', 'my_nmgr_modify_existing_field' );





function save_phone( $extra_data, $wishlist ) {
 if ( isset( $extra_data['nmgr_phone'] ) ) {
        $selected_value = sanitize_text_field( $extra_data['nmgr_phone'] );
        $wishlist_id = $wishlist->get_the_ID();
        $result = update_post_meta( $wishlist_id, 'nmgr_phone', $selected_value );
        if ( $result ) {
            echo '<script>console.log("nmgr_phone value updated: ' . $selected_value . '");</script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script>console.log("Failed to update nmgr_phone value");</script>';
        }
    } } add_action( 'nmgr_save_extra_data', 'save_phone', 10, 2 );
```

Now it seems it does not reach either the update or get_post, as I can't see any value being saved at all. Any tips how to proceed would be appriciated.